# How to write a Unit Test method?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, c#-4.0

I'm new to unit Test Methods. So, can any give me unit test methods for the specified below code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TIPWebITLibrary.DAL;

 public class SearchInfo : IDisposable
    {
        public List<SearchResult> SerialResults { get; set; }
        public List<SearchResult> TagResults { get; set; } 
        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the Search string to filter a resultset by Serial and Tag
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="search"></param>
        public SearchInfo(string search)
        {
            SerialResults = new List<SearchResult>();
            TagResults = new List<SearchResult>();

            SerialResults.AddRange(FindSerial(search));
            TagResults.AddRange(FindTags(search));

        }

        private static IEnumerable<SearchResult> FindTags(string search)
        {

            List<SearchResult> result;
            using (var db = new TIPWebITDataContext())
            {
                result = (from i in db.tblTechInventories
                          where i.Tag.Equals(search)
                          select new SearchResult()
                              {
                                  SearchType = "Tag",
                                  Key = i.Tag,
                                  KeyCaption = i.Tag,
                                  Name = i.tblTechItem.ItemName

                              }).ToList();
            }
            return result;
        }
        private static IEnumerable<SearchResult> FindSerial(string search)
        {
            List<SearchResult> result;
            using (var db = new TIPWebITDataContext())
            {
                result = (from i in db.tblTechInventories
                          where i.Serial.Contains(search)
                          select new SearchResult()
                          {
                              SearchType = "Searial",
                              Key = i.Tag,
                              KeyCaption = i.Serial,
                              Name = i.tblTechItem.ItemName

                          }).ToList();
            }
            return result;

        }

        #region Implementation of IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            SerialResults = null;
            TagResults = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class SearchResult
    {
        public string SearchType { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string KeyCaption { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


}
```

can u please specify me how to write test methods for the above code?

Comment: This is not portal for "how to write", or even "does my code look nice?". Specify concrete problem...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not portal for "how to write", or even "does my code look nice?"

Answer (score 1):

As the one creating your code **YOU** need to know what it is intended to do.
And that is what test methods are for, you want to find out how your software behaves in all (usual and especially unusual, that is where you might have to get creative) cases.

So the simple questions you have to ask yourself are:

- **What parts of my code can be called?**
- **What parameters can my functions take/ what object states can my objects have?**
- **What do I expect to happen in each case (of different parameters/object state)?**

So when you can answer those questions, writing the test methods ought to be trivial ;)

One example to start:

The only thing I see publicly available here is your constructor and the two properties `SerialResults` and `TagResults` so those are the things you want to test. (How I see it the setter for those should probably be private, because you set them in your constructor)

So what different parameters can this constructor take and how should this influence the outcome of your properties? Obviously you want to test for `null values` and `empty strings`, but maybe some `special strings` need to be tested, too, because they have a special meaning in your function, such as: `the whitespace` for example, or maybe you have some `magic string` defined somewhere, all that should go into your unit testing thoughts and afterwards into the testing methods.

A sample structure of a test method could be as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSearchInfoConstructor()
{
    // declare something, initialize something, set it up ;)
    // do something with it that yields a result

    // now call an assert that can fail if something unexpected happens
    Assert.IsTrue(yourCondition);

    // here could start another test case...
}
```

Comment: In my acutal code TestFindTags() is a private method.But, you are specified it's an public. Is it possible.

Comment: @user3567564 oh you are absolutely right! I am sorry. No of course you only have to test what is publicly accessible. I updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: In the above specified code. The main theme is to search a tag. and retrieve a tag from data base. @DrCopyPaste

Comment: @user3567564 Yea, I see. That is what should go into your test method(s). You need to test there that the tag retrieved is always correct / that the content retrieved always "makes" sense and does not provoke unexpected errors or exceptions.

Comment: Can u please suggest me how write test method for the mentioned code. @ DrCopyPaste

Comment: @user3567564 I did suggest you a sample structure for a test method, but implementing the details for your case should be on your side ;)